# Run a function when any textbox changes in a form? MS Access

Tags: forms, vba, ms-access

Is there a way to run a function in VBA the moment data in any control element changes? I've tried Form_AfterUpdate and Form_DataChange but they seem not to do anything

Comment: This is going to be a tricky one, as you have to code all After Update/Change event of the controls in the Form. Or you can check out the On Click event and check if it originated from a control. Or the On Key Press events same logic. Still this will be a long convoluted process.

Comment: Ah I was hoping I wouldn't have to resort to that. Thanks

Comment: I second what @PaulFrancis has stated. That being said, if you shed a little more light on what you need to do, it may be feasible another way.

Comment: It's some basic if statements and calculations based on different text boxes, simple text box value changes.

Comment: And these need to be *on the fly*? I'd love for you to update your question and explain exactly what you are needing to do. This will help everyone involved.

Comment: In the most basic way to explain, I kind of want it to work how an excel spreadsheet works, in terms of some cells having the calculated result of other cell's input information. PaulFrancis' solution seems like the best way to go about this, although it might be a bit tedious in the backend

Answer (score 2):

You do not have to code After Update/Change event of the controls, check out [Key Preview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836983(v=office.15).aspx)

> You can use the KeyPreview property to specify whether the form-level
>   keyboard event procedures are invoked before a control's keyboard
>   event procedures. Read/write Boolean.

Use it carefully.

For example, with KeyPreview on:

```
 Private Sub Form_KeyPress(KeyAscii As Integer)
      MsgBox "You pressed a key"
 End Sub
```

[image: key preview]

Comment: I would not class that as an answer, as I have already mentioned it in the comments this will be a very long process to figure out the source origin, and also KeyPreview events can be a lot more tricky, if you do not know how to use them properly. So a proper solution would be to see what the OP actually needs and suggest a safe and probably a better alternative as OverMind has mentioned !

Comment: I never knew that existed, haha. +1

Comment: @PaulFrancis There is always `Screen.ActiveControl`

Comment: @Fionnuala - again that is not always going to be reliable. This is of course IMVHO. I would not advice the use of Screen.ActiveControl (although that was also hinted in the comment earlier). johnny93, you are welcome to use the answer, but be careful on how you use it. Good luck.

Comment: May I suggest the addition of some code and/or reasoning behind the very explicit "Use it carefully."

Comment: @Overmind The question is vague, and I have given a somewhat vague answer mentioning a property that not everyone is aware of, it is not a canonical answer, and can never be. It was my intention to point out the property, not to provide code when, as you mentioned, there was a shortage of information.

Comment: @Overmind For example, the form KeyPress event will run when *any* control is changed, which is what the OP requested.

Comment: And I 100% agree with you both, but in this scenario it may be better if you provided a "How I would do it is.." form of an answer. I am just thinking that this will help lead to a more 'complete' answer.

Comment: @Fionnuala and yes, I agree that the requirements are silly. OP could also probably use the `Dirty` event in some form/fashion as well.

Comment: @OverMind It depends very much on what you want to do. For example, the user may only wish to say that you should enter a password.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: Create a function

```
Function DoStuff()
    Call RunMySub
End Function
```

Step 2: Create a Macro (Named RunMyCode)

```
RunCode
  Function Name DoStuff()
```

Step 3: Modify the Form_Load() sub

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
Dim cControl As Control
On Error Resume Next
    For Each cControl In Me.Controls
        if cControl.ControlType = 109 'this is for text boxes
            'Depending on what your code does you can use all or some of these:
            cControl.OnExit = "RunMyCode"
            cControl.OnEnter = "RunMyCode"
            cControl.OnLostFocus = "RunMyCode"
            cControl.OnGotFocus = "RunMyCode"
            If cControl.OnClick = "" Then cControl.OnClick = "RunMyCode"
        end if
    Next cControl
On Error GoTo 0
```

You can use any of the attributes from the control I find the pairs of 'OnExit/OnEnter' and 'OnLostFocus/OnGotFocus' to be the most effective. I also like 'OnClick' but I use the if statement to not overwrite actions (for buttons and stuff). There are a dozen other methods you can assign the control action to -- I'm sure you'll be able to find one/several that meet your goal.

Note -- I use the on error enclosure because I wrap this code around multiple different types of controls and not all have all of the methods.

Comment: Since there seems to be no event on form level to achieve the goal, Schalton's code may show a reasonably effective and passably stable way to work around - I think, this answer should be upvoted against the `KeyPress` solution.